# ndk-build not found as a command

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have been working with Android SDK for a while & just came across an requirement to use the NDK

So, I downloaded the Android NDK for Windows. Jumping on the first example, when I am trying to build the library using the process defined in the NDK example

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Specifically the command /ndk-build from the command line

I am getting the error

ndk-build is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have added the path for ndk-build in the PATH variable and even tried calling the command going to the  folder, still the same error

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Have you installed CygWin? "For Windows, Cygwin 1.7 or higher is required. The NDK will not work with Cygwin 1.5 installations."

Comment: Further to @slhck's remark, these commands will ONLY work in Cygwin if you are on PC, you may not run them in DOS.

Answer (score 10):

Guess that should have been an answer instead of a comment.

You must use Cygwin as your shell in order to run ndk-build.
See http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: definitely wrong. u don't need cygwin. windows prompt compiles just fine

Answer (score 2):

Once you have Cygwin installed you can have Eclipse automatically build your project for you by:

1. Right click on your project, pick properties.
2. Select "builders" from the left-hand list.
3. Click "New..." on the right side.
4. Select "Program" as the configuration type. I name mine "Native Builder"

   Location - c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe

   Working Directory - c:\cygwin\bin

   Arguments -

   (for NDK r3):
   --login -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK && make APP=myapp"

   (for NDK r4):
   --login -c "cd /cygdrive/c/ && /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK/ndk-build"

Make sure you have the two hyphens before login and the quotes after the hyphen-c

5. Now go to the refresh tab
6. Check "Refresh resources upon completion"
7. Select "Specific resources"
8. Click on the "Specify resources" button and select your project's
   lib directory.
9. Check "Recursively include sub-folders"
10. Now go to the build options tab
11. Check "Allocate Console"
12. Check "Launch in background"
13. Check "Run the builder After a Clean"
14. Check "Run the builder During manual builds"
15. Check "Run the builder During auto builds"
16. Check "Specify working set of relevant resources"
17. Click on "Specify Resources"
18. Select your project's JNI directory and all files within.
19. Now click OK on the bottom.

Now you can edit and save in your c files and it will compile and create the .so file on the fly.

Comment: I followed your approach  but i am getting `Please install Cygwin make package or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.` do you have any idea to solve this

Comment: And your positive that you installed cygwin first?  Latest Eclipse version doesn't require you to install cygwin anymore.

Comment: i solve that `GNUMAKE` error by re installing cygwin but if i set ndk-build without using cygwin in eclipse then i am getting error which says `it is not valid win 32 app`

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing 32 and 64 bit programs.  You have to make sure all programs are the same bit size

Comment: No longer needed in the latest versions of eclipse NDK compiler included in Android tools

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your development IDE hides system PATH and uses it's own PATH. I had same problem with MOTODEV Eclipse for Android 3.1. Detailed solution is here: [How to solve problem with Motodev Eclipse for Android 3.1: wrong PATH](http://serpents-iz.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-solve-problem-with-motodev.html)  It is for MOTODEV IDE, but Eclipse may have same thing.