# ndk-build and command not found using Eclipse mac

Tags: android, eclipse, bash, android-ndk

I am developing and android application in mac using Eclipse for android-ndk. I have already given NDK path in Eclipse. At the end when I am giving this command to build my application using android-ndk but getting the following errors:

`command: ndk-build`

```
ndk-build-bash: ndk-build: command not found
```

[image]

My Terminal Commands:

```
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:~ UsmanKhan$ cd downloads
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:downloads UsmanKhan$ cd 26thMarch2014
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:26thMarch2014 UsmanKhan$ cd a2zLatest
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ls
AndroidManifest.xml gen         proguard-project.txt
Thumbs.db       ic_launcher-web.png project.properties
assets          libs            res
bin         lint.xml        src
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ls bin/classes/
com
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ls bin/classes/com/testing/ndk
BuildConfig.class   R$dimen.class       R$string.class
FibLib.class        R$drawable.class    R$style.class
MainActivity.class  R$id.class      R.class
R$attr.class        R$layout.class
R$color.class       R$menu.class
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ mkdir jni
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ javah -jni -classpath bin /classes/ -d jni/ com.testing.ndk.FibLib
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ls jni
com_testing_ndk_FibLib.h
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ls jni
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.testing.ndk.FibLib
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.testing.ndk.FibLib
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:a2zLatest UsmanKhan$ ndk-build
-bash: ndk: command not found
```

At the end i am getting ndk-build error.

Comment: could you provide some screenshots on how you defined the ndk path in eclipse?

Comment: What are the values of `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`? Also see [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ) on the Android NDK mailing list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ndk-build not found in Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312311/ndk-build-not-found-in-path) and [ndk-build not found as a command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5847532/608639).

Comment: @jww thanks for your reply. I didn't give any explicit values for ANDROID_NDK_ROOT and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, i just give the location of my NDK in my eclipse preferences. Can you please guide me in this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ndk-build` command, simply type `~/Desktop/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't give any explicit values for ANDROID_NDK_ROOT and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, i just give the location of my NDK in my eclipse preferences. Can you please guide me in this thing

According to the Android folks on the Android NDK group (see [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ)), uou should always provide values for `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. Here is what they are used for:

- `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` → installation dirctory of NDK
- `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` → installation dirctory of SDK
- `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` → location of SDK-related user files, defaults to `~/.android/` on Unix.

Put the tools on-path and export the env vars. Here's my `.bash_profile` for OS X.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
export PS1="\h::\W$ "

# Android
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r10d
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk-macosx
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/.android

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/":"$PATH"
```

Then, [`source` your profile changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21211281/608639) (or log-off and then log-in).

Comment: i am very new to MAC OSX, can you please give me little bit more example that how can i apply it on my terminal. I have seen the link but it didn't help me. I just closes my Terminal and opened it again. Please tell me where to put these command to make my path set for ndk. Thanks

Comment: @UKhan - See [How to add a line to .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/q/678113/173513) on Super User. If it helps you, then you should upvote the question and answer.