# "Error: Android SDK not found" when building ionic app

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

I created an Ionic Project named "HelloWorld" . I am able to run it in browser. Trying to run it in android mobile, when I build I'm getting this issue. Pls help me out.

command I gave:   `ionic build android`

Error thrown:

```
Running command: /home/infibeam/gittry3/mytest/ionic_ex/HelloWorld/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/infibeam/gittry3/mytest/ionic_ex/HelloWorld

add to body class: platform-android

ERROR building one of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

My configurations of the environmental variables in .bashrc files goes like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/infibeam/android-sdk-linux/docs/sdk"
export ANDROID_SDK="/home/infibeam/android-sdk-linux/docs/sdk"
export ANDROID_NDK="/home/infibeam/android-sdk-linux/docs/ndk"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

All these paths are valid. I have checked on it!

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME="/home/infibeam/android-sdk-linux/docs/sdk"` is probably wrong. It is usually located at `$HOME/.android`. Also see [ndk-build and command not found using eclipse mac](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30138016/608639), which provides the location for the variables with references.